# SQL table primary key's index is starting at 3

Tags: mysql, sql

I set the column Id to the primary key and set it to increment but its starting at 3 for some reason. I will post a picture below:
[Sql table not incrementing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfz81.png)

Comment: Why would you care if it starts with 3 or 1000???

Comment: @Eric honestly i didn't really know. I have never seen that happen when setting up a table and making my id a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ALTER TABLE` statement to reset the auto-increment counter, but I would urge you not to be concerned about it.  The value of a primary key is supposed to be *"meaningless and* unique."  Even across time.  It doesn't matter if it started counting with 3.

Comment: really? thats good to know then. I have never seen that happen before while creating a table so I just had to ask and I couldnt figure out how to change it. I guess ill leave it alone. Thank you for the help!

Comment: That's it. Probably you have been trying to set you table up and inserted and deleted three records. Agree 100% with @Mike Robinson